# ReactJS render then click handler not picking up element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my React component I have

```
render() {
    return (
        <div className="brandlab-asset brandlab-asset-color js-color" onClick={this.handleColor}>
```

then in handleColor in that same file I have

```
handleColor (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const color$ = document.getElementsByClassName('.js-color')[0];
    this.colorPicker.anchor$ = evt.target;
    color$.classList.add('editing');
```

It returns an error saying that `Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined`. I'm guessing `document.getElementsByClassName('.js-color')[0]` is undefined, but it's rendered on the page?

Answer (score 2):

remove `.`

```
document.getElementsByClassName('js-color')[0];
```